# Button are not aligned when screen is narrow

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I would like to align button in order to make responsive my web application.
The button are correctly aligned when the screen is large :

[Button correctly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM1KU.png)

Here is a capture when the button are not correctly aligned :

[Button not correctly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXA7e.png)

This is the sample :

```css
  body{
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
  #message_bienvenue{
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #bouton_mission{
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  #livraison_chauffeur{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 90%;
  }
  
  .container-fluid{
    margin-top: 70px !important;
  }

  /* BOUTON */
  .btn-circle.btn-xl {
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 45px;
    font-size: 34px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5px
  }
  
  .btn-circle.btn-xl img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  
  .text-button{
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  
  .text-button label{
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  
  .block-mission{
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .block-mission label{
      margin-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .btn-1 {
      background-image: url("https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/icon-ok-png-2.png");
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
  }
  
  .btn-2 {
      background-image: url("https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/icon-ok-png-2.png");
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
  }
  
  .btn-3 {
      background-image: url("https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/icon-ok-png-2.png");
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <link rel="icon" href="">
 <title>Title</title>
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" integrity="sha384-mKB41Eu6sQQvXR8fqvXcVe8SXodkH6cYtVvHkvLwE7Nq0R/+coO4yJispNYKy9iZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 0px !important">
  <form method="post" action="requetes/page.php" role="form" id="formulaire">
  <h3>Créer mission :</h3>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="numero_bon" type="number" min="0" name="numero_bon" placeholder="Numéro de bon de livraison" required>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="nom_client" name="nom_client" type="text" placeholder="Client" required>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="adresse_client" name="adresse_client" type="text" placeholder="Adresse" required>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="volume_livraison" type="number" name="volume_livraison" placeholder="M³" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01" formnovalidate required>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="nom_centrale"type="text" name="nom_centrale" placeholder="Centrale" required>
  <hr/>
  <span class="label label-default">Zone</span>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="zone" type="text" name="zone">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
   <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
   <option>11</option>
   <option>12</option>
   <option>13</option>
   <option>14</option>
   <option>15</option>
   <option>16</option>
   <option>17</option>
   <option>18</option>
   <option>19</option>
   <option>20</option>
  </select>
  <hr/>

  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 0 !important">
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center block-mission">
          <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small btn-1" id="creer_mission_replacee" name="type_voyage" value="Replacé" type="submit">
          </button>
            <label>Voyage validé replacé</label>
        </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center block-mission">
     <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small btn-2" id="creer_mission" name="type_voyage" value="Livré" type="submit">
      </button>
      <label>Livraison effectuée validée</label>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center block-mission">
     <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small btn-3" id="creer_mission_annulee" name="type_voyage" value="Annulé" type="submit">
      </button>
      <label>Voyage annulé</label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Someone could fix my code ? I don't know how to do it ? To the problem : Click on `Run code snippet` --> `Full page` --> Reduce your browser border to the minimum.

Comment: Hi Maria, I would advise you to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For btn-circle class use this code

```css
.btn-circle {
  width: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 40px;
}
```

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, it sounds like you do not want the buttons to lose their alignment in that you would like to see them stay in a row on one line as they are in the desktop view. If that's true, then you can fix that by adding a property and value to the '.justify-content-around' class like this.

```css
.justify-content-around {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Here's a really great guide to flexbox CSS: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Potentially, however, you may want to attempt a more mobile-friendly alignment of the button which would probably change things a bit, but perhaps just shrinking the buttons a little in mobile view will help too. And if that's the case, Udayavani's answer above would be useful in combination with mine, using a media query at the break-point in which you would like to see the change, like so:

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .btn-circle {
        width: 40px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: auto;
        height: 40px;
    }

}
```

Here's a reference for media queries:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Bootstrap col to each div in a row for it. like this:

```
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 0 !important">
        <div class="row justify-content-around">
            <div class="col flex-column align-items-center block-mission">
                <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small btn-1" id="creer_mission_replacee" name="type_voyage" value="Replacé" type="submit">
  </button>
                <label>Voyage validé replacé</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col flex-column align-items-center block-mission">
                <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small btn-2" id="creer_mission" name="type_voyage" value="Livré" type="submit">
                </button>
                <label>Livraison effectuée validée</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col flex-column align-items-center block-mission">
                <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small btn-3" id="creer_mission_annulee" name="type_voyage" value="Annulé" type="submit">
                </button>
                <label>Voyage annulé</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

see:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/gkduhbs2/

Answer (score 0):

just remove the class "row" if you still want them to align horizontally, but you might have to resize your button text to look really nice.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parrent_div{display:flex;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:row;
}
.button {
width:100%
}
```

it will auto align your elements as per screen resolution